# Помогите с идеями как такое можно реализовать

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

появилась необходимость реализовать такой блок http://joxi.ru/V2VE5EjcKndbjm и у меня нет вообще никаких  идей как это сделать без оборачивания каждой строки в отдельный div или другой какой тег. Мне не очень нравится мысль с оберткой каждой строки в отдельный тег т.к. такой подход при адаптивной верстке смотреться не очень на некоторых разрешениях.

Comment: Ты хочешь реализовать блок с "тэгами"? Что должно происходить если нажать на один из них?
Попробуй описать задачу более корректно. Тогда смогу предложить пару мыслей!

Comment: В чём сложность?

Comment: Это просто ссылки, этот блок будет виден на экранах больше 1024px, меньше этого разрешения будет скрываться, если строк будет больше чем 3, то остальные строки должны быть размера как самая нижняя третья строка из скрина http://joxi.ru/V2VE5EjcKndbjm. сложность, что у каждой строки разный font-size и opacity

Comment: Это скрин с сайта? Можно ссылку?

Comment: Навскидку, можно разный font-size и opacity делать элементам, исходя из их очередноcти (nth-of-type). А чтобы очередность точно соответствовала, каждый тег будет занимать точно, допустим, 20% ширины

Comment: это скрин с макета, я пока не реализовал этот блок

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/c2th7gkj/

Comment: спасибо, но выше я описывал, почему не хочу использовать такой вариант